# properties of an app run-as-an-eclipse-application

Tags: java, eclipse

As the title says, I have an app that is run as an eclipse application.
I want to change the properties by adding a new field to it.
how can I access it? where do I find it?

Edit: by properties I mean the eclipse workbench properties view that is used to view or modify properties of a selected item.

Comment: Sorry but this is far too vague and broad. Do you mean you have an Eclipse RCP application? We can't tell you how to change the app since it requires detailed knowledge of the RCP design which you haven't told us about.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "properties" and "new field"? If you mean the system properties, you can specify additional vm arguments in the arguments tab of your run configuration. There you can add system properties with the standard java argument -Dname=value

Comment: I edited the question. Does that clarify what I'm asking about?

Comment: This is still far too broad. Changing the properties view requires details about the RCP design. What **exactly** do you want to add? For what type of object? Are the objects part of your RCP code or provided by standard Eclipse plugins?